# How do I concatenate this raw query properly with a variable in android?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, linq, sqlite

This is my raw query on android.

```
 Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+dbn LIMIT 5;, null);
```

Can someone fix the syntax error on this line of code?
I'm trying to concatenate the query with a variable and want to limit 5 entries in output, and that **`LIMIT 5`** is not properly concatenated with the query. There is missing of double quotes or single quotes.

I tried a lot to fix this.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: `("SELECT * FROM "+dbn +" LIMIT 5;", null);`

Comment: You don't need to pass ; at the end. If you are using raw queriy

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh thanks. it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` is a syntax not a variable so you need to put `LIMIT` into `""`. 
And at the place of 5 you can write a variable which is `5` in value.

```
int VAL=5;
Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + dbn + " LIMIT " + VAL + ";", null);
```

And if you don't want to use a variable at the place of 5 then write like this:

```
Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + dbn + " LIMIT 5;", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

please check below query for limit it might be help to resolve your issues.

```
return wDb.query("tablename", null, null, null, null, null, String.valueOf(5));
```

You can also refer the below links for more information regarding sql query

[More About SQL Query](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-stmt)